# How do I add a SERVER_NAME to expressjs app like done in Flask app

Tags: node.js, express

I have a simple `express` app.

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express()
var [host, port] = ["mynodepage.com", 80];

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello Worlds');
})

app.listen(port, host, () => {
    console.log("Starting server on " + host + ":" + port);
});
```

Why doesn't that run one "mynodepage.com", when the python app:

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "Hello World"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    website_url = "mynodepage.com:80"
    app.config["SERVER_NAME"] = website_url
    app.run()
```

works fine. I followed the tutorial provided by [`https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/subdomain-in-flask-python/`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/subdomain-in-flask-python/), and my python app works file. Why doesn't that work with express?
Or, am I doing some thing wrong? Is there any way to get my express app on `mynodepage.com`?

Comment: What is not working? Are you just playing around or do you want either Express or Flask to work?

Comment: I flask, I can make my code run on any domain name I want by configuring the DNS in the `driver` directory. Is there any way to run my express app also on any domain name?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to define the host when using the `app.listen(..)` function. The following code will fix the issue:

```
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Starting server on " + host + ":" + port);
});
```

Comment: ok, on which port does that run?

Comment: ah my mistake.. it should be 

app.listen(port, () => {
console.log("Starting server on " + host + ":" + port);
});

and then you can access it on http://localhost/